# JMagick Configure File Unable to Locate Java Directories

Tags: java, linux, virtual-machine, jmagick

I am new to Linux and am working on a VM. I am trying to configure my `JMagick` installation, however when I run `./configure` I receive an error saying that it is 'Unable to locate Java directories:'

```
./configure

checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables...
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking for getconf... /usr/bin/getconf
checking whether large file support needs explicit enabling... no
checking for X... libraries , headers
configure: error: 'Unable to locate Java directories'
```

I know that the `configure` is looking for `java`, `javac`, `jar`, and `gcc`. When I type `whereis` on each of these items I see that they are all on my `$PATH` in `/usr/bin` (I even added each to the path individually):

```
PATH=/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin:/usr/bin/java:/usr/bin/javac:/usr/bin/jar:/usr/bin/gcc

whereis java javac jar gcc

java: /usr/bin/java  /etc/java  /usr/lib/java  /usr/share/java /usr/share/man/man1/java.1.gz
javac: /usr/bin/javac  /usr/share/man/man1/javac.1.gz
jar: /usr/bin/jar  /usr/share/man/man1/jar.1.gz
gcc: /usr/bin/gcc  /usr/lib/gcc  /usr/libexec/gcc  /usr/share/man/man1/gcc.1.gz
```

From what I was able to find, I believe I need to set a `JAVA_HOME` environmental variable. So I did:

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/bin/java
```

Nevertheless, I still get the `Unable to locate Java directories` error. As I said I am new to Linux and am pretty stuck and unsure about what to do. Any ideas as to what I am doing incorrectly?

If it is at all relevant, the current versions of the various technologies running on the VM are:

```
java version "1.7.0_09-icedtea"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (rhel-2.3.4.1.el6_3-x86_64)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.2-b09, mixed mode)

javac 1.7.0_09

gcc (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `yum install java-1.6.0-openjdk java-1.6.0-openjdk-devel`
2. `tar zxvf Jmagick.xx.xx`
3. `cd` the dir
4. `./configure --prefix=/usr/local/imagemagick/ -with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.38.x86_64/`
5. done

Answer (score -2):

JMagick requires installing jdk1.6, try this:

```
yum install java-1.6.0-openjdk java-1.6.0-openjdk-devel
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12066245)

Comment: 1. yum install java-1.6.0-openjdk java-1.6.0-openjdk-devel;